# How to refresh cache on file updates in IIS

Tags: html, iis, caching

My client has an IIS instance hosting sites containing non project based sites (just html js and css content). Due to the nature of the data the sites contain my client wants a better solution to caching than just a timeout that is set within the HTTP response headers to avoid encountering any outdated content.

My question would be how do I refresh the IIS cache when the site contents (http and JS) is updated?

I have seen there is an 'Output Caching' option with 'cache until change' options for file extensions but it doesn't seem to work as I expect.
I have also read that PowerShell can be used to monitor files and integrate with IIS settings but was wondering if there was a simpler way as I have no experience with PowerShell.

Comment: Welcome on SO! "How to" and "What is the best" are two different question. And the second is off-topic. You can read [ask] for more

Comment: Recycle the application pool in IIS or running iisreset, simple and convenient.